# Problem related to temperary border in Blender 2D

Tags: 2d

I know that we can create a temporary border by alt + LMB. However it doesn't work on my computer. It switchs to other dimensions instead. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: IDK what a temporary border is, ALT LMB does nothing with my setup. Do you want to restrict render, view, 3D view?

Comment: @Frederik Steinmetz 
Sorry for unclear, I mean the temporary boundary stroke for filling color in an open area.